# Comparing two pandas dataframes on column and the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, correlation

I have two pandas dataframes that look about the same but with different information stored in them. My question will be about how to compare the two dataframes to ensure column and row match before performing some analysis and to obtain a third dataframe of the correlation between the two.

df1 (50x14492):

```
TYPE GENRE1 GENRE2
Name1 .0945 .0845
Name2 .9074 Nan
Name3 1     0
```

and df2 (50x14492):

```
TYPE GENRE1 GENRE2
Name1 .9045 .895
Name2 .074  1
Name3 .5    .045
```

Hoped for result df3 that is as yet unobtained(50x14492):

```
TYPE GENRE1                  GENRE2
Name1 spearsonr(.9045,.9045) spearsonr(.0845,.895)
Name2 spearsonr(.9074,.074)  spearsonr(Nan,1)
Name3 spearsonr(1,.5)        spearsonr(0,.045)
```

I'd like to compare df1.GENRE1.Name1 to df2.GENRE1.Name1 but am getting lost in the implementation. In order to do this I have the following code:

```
for key1, value1 in df1.iteritems():
    for key2, value2 in df2.iteritems():
        if key1 == key2:
           # this gets me to df1.GENRE1 == df2.GENRE1
           for newkey1, newval1 in key1.iterrows():
               for newkey2, newval2 in key2.iterrows():
                   if newkey1 == newkey2:
                      # this does not seem to get me to df1.GENRE1.Name1 == df2.GENRE1.Name1
                      scipy.stats.spearmanr(newval1, newval2)
```

This is allowing me to compare df1.GENRE1 and df2.GENRE1 but I am not sure how to get to the next logical step of also ensuring that df1.GENRE1.Name1 == df2.GENRE1.Name1. Another way to put it, I am unsure of how to ensure the rows match now that I have the columns.

NOTE: 
I have tried to use spearmanr on the full two dataframes as such:

```
corr, p_val = scipy.stats.spearmanr(df1, df2, axis=0, nan_policy='omit')
```

but rather than getting a new dataframe of the same size (50x14492) I am getting a table back that's 100x100.

Similarly if I use:

```
corr, p_val = scipy.stats.spearmanr(df1['GENRE1'], df2['GENRE1'], axis=0, nan_policy='omit')
```

I get the correlation of the two columns as a whole, rather than each row of that column. (Which would be of size 1X14492)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that if 'Type' is set as an index, mostly all of pandas operations are done with intrinsic data alignment.  So, there isn't a need to make sure that columns and rows are in the same order between the two dataframes.  If you simply do df1 + df2, it will add each dataframe together using the indexes to align the data.

Comment: @ScottBoston I'm not sure I understand your meaning here. When I attempted to use scipy.stats.spearmanr(df1, df2) I got less rows and columns back than I submitted, but I wanted one to one comparisons of each cell in the dataframe, which leads me to believe I would have to iterate through the dataframes this way. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit convoluted. Are you trying to get the correlation between the two Genre columns?

If so you can simply call the correlation on the two columns in the DataFrame:

```
scipy.stats.spearmanr(df1['GENRE1'], df2['GENRE1'])
```

After reading your comment and edits, it appears you want the correlation row-wise. That's a simple CS problem but you should know that you're not going to get anything meaningful out of taking the correlation between two values. It'll just be undefined or 1. Anyway, this should populate df3 as you requested above:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3['genre1'] = map(spearmanr, zip(df1['genre1'], df2['genre1']))
df3['genre2'] = map(spearmanr, zip(df1['genre2'], df2['genre2']))
```

Comment: If you do the spearmanr correlation on the column then you get the correlation between the two columns. I want the correlation of every row in the two columns. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @ Stephopolis, that makes more sense but I think you're misunderstanding correlation. See my edits above.